# EditText values are not reflected it shows previous value but when you print getText of Editext it shows correct value

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-viewpager, object-reference

I am using ViewPager(FragmentStatePagerAdapter) my Adapter is as below

```
private static class CreateSalesOrderSectionAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
    {
        public CreateSalesOrderSectionAdapter(FragmentManager fm) 
        {
            super(fm);

//          mSalesOrderGeneralFragment = new SalesOrderGeneralFragment();
//          mSalesOrderProductFragment = new SalesOrderProductFragment();
//          mSalesOrderAddressFragment = new SalesOrderAddressFragment();
//          
//          mSalesOrderGeneralFragment.setArguments(intentData);
//          mSalesOrderProductFragment.setArguments(intentData);
//          mSalesOrderAddressFragment.setArguments(intentData);

        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            switch (position)
            {
            case 0:
                return mSalesOrderGeneralFragment;
            case 1:
                return mSalesOrderProductFragment;
            case 2:
                return mSalesOrderAddressFragment;
            default:
                break;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return 3;
        }
    }
```

In one of the Fragment I am setting a EditText text it works perfectly first time but it does not reflect the change when I change the user from another fragment it remain same previous text but when I print the value of EditText it shows the updated text but updated text are not reflected it shows previous text.

But when I uncomment the lines which are commented in Adapter it works perfectly I not able to understand why it's happening. I want to know what was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting value in edit text because ViewPager is not refreshed, rather its GUI is not refreshed, programatically when you change the text it is changed, and you are getting that, so now you only need to notify the ViewPager or refresh its view. If notifydatasetchanged not working then try setting adapter once again...

Comment: I have notified the viewpager but it didn't work when I created new reference of Fragement it works

Comment: Yes I tried that also not worked I just want to why creating new object of Fragment worked what is logic behind it.

Comment: Bro there is no logic behind this..the reason behind it is that adapter is not getting refresh. This happens generally in adapter children, When any controls are used directly then this does not happens because you directly call that control and refresh it. Here your main control is viewpager so you nedd to refresh it.

Comment: there is no question of being refreshed or not As I am saying I refreshed the adapter but didn't worked but when I created a  new reference of Fragment it worked So just I want to know why it didn't work without creating new reference of fragment.